# HTML Marquee style not working

Tags: html, marquee

I am trying to run text from a database as a marquee. The marquee must occupy 10% of the total screen height, on the bottom of the screen.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
<font color="#FFFFFF" size="+1" face="Verdana"><marquee bgcolor="#FF0000" style="height: 10%; bottom: 0; " scrollamount="5">Your text here</marquee></font>
<div>
```

It does not occypy 10% and is not at the bottom of the page. What am I missing?

Comment: What's your doctype? The <font> tag is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>

Comment: [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp) recommend you replace <font> with CSS. See if that fixes the issue. If not, could you provide us with a preview link?

Comment: The font tag cannot be the issue. The color att works

Comment: `bottom: 0` but positioned how? `absolute`?

Comment: `height: 10%` of what? Where's the parent element `height` being defined?

Comment: `<font>` and `<marquee>` have been both long deprecated.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - Any alternative to `<marquee>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you forgot '/' in your closing div tag, but it is not critical. For your `height: 10%` to work, you have to fix the parent element `height`, for instance set `height: 100%` to the div. Then, for `bottom:0` to work, position should be absolute, and parent positionning should be relative:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
        <font color="#FFFFFF" face="Verdana" size="+1"><marquee style="height: 10%; bottom: 0px; position: absolute;" scrollamount="5" bgcolor="#FF0000">Your text here</marquee></font>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps